# About program export variables

Tags: c++builder, dllexport, declspec

The graphics card manufacturer has an optimization scheme. The following variables are exported from the program, and the program will be executed with an independent graphics card. For the program compiled by the new version of the bcc compiler, the exported variables are prefixed with an underscore, and the `-vu` parameter is not supported. I don't know how to solve this.

```
// http://developer.download.nvidia.com/devzone/devcenter/gamegraphics/files/OptimusRenderingPolicies.pdf
// The following line is to favor the high performance NVIDIA GPU if there are multiple GPUs
// Has to be .exe module to be correctly detected.
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;

// And the AMD equivalent
// Also has to be .exe module to be correctly detected.
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 0x00000001;
```

bcc32 old version

[image]

bcc32c new version

[image]

Comment: The IDE has an option to pass user-defined parameters to the compiler.  Try specifying the `-fno-leading-underscore` switch.

Comment: [bcc32c Error] unknown argument: '-fno-leading-underscore'

Comment: Does `-fno-underscoring` work?

Comment: bcc32c -fno-underscoring main.cpp

Comment: E2075 Incorrect command line option: -fno-underscoring

Comment: Embarcadero C++ 7.50 for Win32

Comment: Then I don't know what else to true. I got those switches from gcc's and clang's documentations. I guess Embarcadero doesn't implement them